# wrong test count with maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: maven, junit, counter, maven-surefire-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
            <phantomjs.binary.path>src/test/resources/drivers/%s/phantomjs/%s/phantomjs%s</phantomjs.binary.path>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*UT.java</include>
            <include>**/CucumberRunner.java</include>
        </includes>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.637 sec - in com.company.my.package.YourStepsUT

Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.373 sec - in com.company.my.package.MyStepsUT

Tests run: 1739, Failures: 60, Errors: 4, Skipped: 237, Time elapsed: 2,066.116 sec <<< FAILURE! - in CucumberRunner

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in com.company.utils.MyContextUT

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in com.company.utils.MyMessagesUT


Tests run: 1744, Failures: 60, Errors: 4, Skipped: 227

[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Each counter is good but not the sum of all counters at the end in the summary

**My problem is the wrong test count**

So run:5+8+1739+1+1 = **1754 != 1744**

So Skipped:0+0+237+0+0 = **237 != 227**

I have:
Tests run: **1744**, Failures: 60, Errors: 4, Skipped: **227**

Comment: Make sure you try with the latest version, which is 2.19.1

Comment: @Tunaki, I try with 2.19.1 but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in cucumber-jvm. Fixed in version 2.x.x